# CodeBlocks gives "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)", with 0 error nd 0 warning when I create a linked list cycle

Tags: c, linked-list, codeblocks

When I use the Code::Blocks,I want to create a doubly Linked List.

And I want to use an array to create the nodes whose type are struct*.

I suspect this is where the bug comes from.

And also I don't know that: if I give an Variable N to create a[N], will it be wrong?

And the compiler gives me result of 0 error nd 0 warning, but it returns -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Do you know where is the wrong place?
Thank you in advance!

here are my codes

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//define a node
typedef struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    struct ListNode* next;
}ListNode;
//construct a linked list Cycle
ListNode *makecycle(int N)
{
    int i;
    ListNode* a[N]; //can I create an array using N?
    a[1]->next = a[2];
    a[1]->val = 1;
    for(i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i]->next = a[i+1];
        a[i]->val = i;
    }
    a[N]->next = a[1];
    a[N]->val = N;
    return a[1];
}
//input needed variables
int main()
{
    int N, A, B, K;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &N, &A, &B, &K);

    ListNode *head = makecycle(N);
    while(head) {
        printf("%d ", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `a[]` is an array of uninitialized pointers.

Comment: so should I malloc from 1 to N?

Comment: Thank you very much sincerely. I added the

 for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    }

and it runs well.

Comment: `a[]` is also an `auto` variable, it will be erased when it goes out of scope. Not that it matters at all, you only really need a pointer to the first and the last value.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is the windows equivalent of a Posix segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing `a[]` as such,

[image: a[]]

then you are assigning the non-existent garbage data values, which will result in undefined behaviour. Then the `auto` variable `a[]` goes out-of-scope, and if it hasn't crashed, you've just written some random place in the memory and returned an uninitialized value. With `malloc` initializing the pointers, this program is much better behaved,

[image: a[] with values initialized]

This will return the pointer to `a[1]`, and all other values are memory leaks because all other values of `a` are out-of-scope when the function returns. You are probably looking for something like this,

[image: Circular linked list.]

You might do this by initializing pointers soon after you create them. You actually don't need an `a[]` at all, you could do this in-place by using pointers to `struct ListNode`:

- keeping `head` at 0;
- having `tail` be the last one you've constructed;
- having `before_tail` link up to `tail`;
- when you are done, link `tail` to `head` to complete the cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much! I realize that an array of structs is not necessary. :)

Answer (score 0):

as @Eugene Sh. says, the `a[]`is an array of uninitilized pointers.
so I added

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
 { 
    a[i] = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
 }
```

and it runs now
so I see that if I give an Variable N to create a[N], it will not be wrong.
and returning -1073741819 (0xC0000005) maybe a problem of not giving a place to the pointer,
or not initilazing the pointer.